# C++ header file not found while compiling aws-sdk-cpp for QNX using cmake command

Tags: cmake, qnx, aws-sdk-cpp

[screenshot for build.make file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIDf4.png)

When compiling the aws-sdk-cpp for AWS FWE for QNX. I am able to compile for C files.
C++ files compilation is throughing an error as below:

```
[ 38%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-event-stream/CMakeFiles/aws-c-event-stream.dir/source/event_stream_rpc_server.c.o
[ 38%] Linking C static library ../../../../lib/libaws-c-event-stream.a
[ 38%] Built target aws-c-event-stream
[ 38%] Building CXX object crt/aws-crt-cpp/CMakeFiles/aws-crt-cpp.dir/source/Allocator.cpp.o
/home/user/AWSSDK/Oct19/aws-sdk-cpp/crt/aws-crt-cpp/source/Allocator.cpp:5:10: fatal error: aws/crt/Allocator.h: No such file or directory
 #include <aws/crt/Allocator.h>
compilation terminated.
crt/aws-crt-cpp/CMakeFiles/aws-crt-cpp.dir/build.make:76: recipe for target 'crt/aws-crt-cpp/CMakeFiles/aws-crt-cpp.dir/source/Allocator.cpp.o' failed
```

Tried to deep digger for the issue and my understanding is that, header flags are not getting included correctly.
I have take the sdk from the link :- [https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp](https://stackoverflow.com)
and for porting cmake for qnx project :- [https://www.qnx.com/support/knowledgebase.html?id=5011O000001OLcS](https://stackoverflow.com)

NOTE:
Attached image is the command for building the file above in question with command(cmake generated file). I assume CXX_INCLUDES is not able to recognize in the command

Can any one help on how/which flag to use for the header file inclusion using cmake command for above error.
I as able to compile C files.

I have tried to manually provide the Include path, it doesn't compile fully, still getting error for other files.
Think i am missing something in the cmake flags to be included.